# The curl `-u` can convert to what if I use the Ajax for http request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, curl

The curl `-u` can convert to what if I use the Ajax for http request?

```
curl -u name:password www.secrets.com
```

you see I use curl -u to request a api.

if I use Ajax, the -u will be convert to what ?

I have a http request util method:

```
var http_util = function (type, url, params, headers, success_handler, error_handler, base_url) {

    if(base_url) {
        url = base_url + url;
    }

    var success = arguments[3]?arguments[3]:function(){};
    var error = arguments[4]?arguments[4]:function(){};

    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: params,
        headers: headers,
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {

            if(textStatus === 'success'){
                success(xhr.code, data)
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, error_text, statusText) {

            error(xhr.code, xhr);
        }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `username` and `password` to your `ajax` request like this

```
var http_util = function (type, url, params, headers, success_handler, error_handler, base_url) {

    if(base_url) {
        url = base_url + url;
    }

    var success = arguments[3]?arguments[3]:function(){};
    var error = arguments[4]?arguments[4]:function(){};

    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: params,
        headers: headers,
        username: name,
        password: password,
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {

            if(textStatus === 'success'){
                success(xhr.code, data)
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, error_text, statusText) {

            error(xhr.code, xhr);
        }
    })

}
```